# Awk-How remove pattern with brackets

Tags: awk, brackets

I made a mistake, adding Ini file (Yes we're in 2022 :D) a section with errors

I added a line [End[edit=true]

How could remove this entire line using awk (I don't have any others choice )

I don't understand how escape the [ in the AWK command line.

Could you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: why not manually edit the file and remove the line?

Comment: Oh sorry. I've add it on the same file but on 145 remotes computers.... And values are differents on each pc so I can send one file on each pc....

Comment: same exact *ini file on all 145 computers? if 'yes' ... manually edit locally and then re-run your push operation (ie, whatever you did to push the file in the first place)?

Comment: No, it would be so easy 

Comment: In stead of `awk`., you can do this with grep: `grep -v '\[End\[edit=true\]' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple ideas where you escape the leading (left) brackets:

```
awk '/\[End\[edit=true]/ {next} 1' file

# or

awk '!/\[End\[edit=true]/' file
```

Once you've confirmed the results, and assuming you're using `GNU awk`, you can add `-i inplace` to update the file:

```
awk -i inplace '!/\[End\[edit=true]/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand how escape the [ in the AWK command line.

If line is always literal `[End[edit=true]` then you do not need to, just request lines which are not that one following way, let `file.ini` content be

```
[someline=true]
[End[edit=true]
[another=true]
```

then

```
awk '$0!="[End[edit=true]"' file.ini
```

gives output

```
[someline=true]
[another=true]
```

Explanation: `$0` denotes whole line, if it is not `[End[edit=true]` then it is `print`ed.

(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)